# What does "a roll of fifty was worth a thousand American dollars" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Source: [The Secret Cycle](http://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2009/10/12/the-secret-cycle)

> The next year, he bought several bags of rare Canadian pennies, which turned out to be even rarer than he thought. Within a year, they shot up in value: **a roll of fifty was worth a thousand American dollars**.

What does the bold part mean?

Comment: Fifty what? Twenty-dollar bills?

Comment: I just got that line from the New Yorker magazine

Comment: It means "X [a roll of fifty] was worth a thousand American dollars." As to what "a roll of fifty" means, we can only guess.

Comment: Can you give more of the original quote?

Comment: You're supposed to provide [more details](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please), like a larger portion of the text, a link if possible, and any research you have done to answer your own question. Also, include your own attempt or clearly explain which word or grammar confuses you.

Comment: http://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2009/10/12/the-secret-cycle

Comment: a roll of fifty was worth a thousand American dollars. Since he had roughly a thousand rolls, he became, for a brief spell, a teen-age millionaire. Expecting, as people do, that the pennies’ price would keep rising, he held on to them, but the high price precipitated the discovery of a greater supply, their value plunged, and he was once again a regular South Jersey kid working weekends in a coin shop.

Comment: "A roll of fifty" probably means a sealed roll of penny (one cent) coins, as they would be supplied by a bank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

In this case, *roll* refers to one of these: a coin wrapper filled with coins. Moreover, it is implied that the kind of coins were the rare Canadian pennies.

> Within a year, they shot up in value: a roll of fifty [**Canadian pennies**] was worth a thousand American dollars.

In other words, the wrapper contained 50 rare Canadian pennies, and within a year, the value of these 50 Canadian pennies was one thousand American dollars—20 dollars per penny.

Comment: Max I am speechless the way you explained with figure.Awesome.Max

Answer (score 3):

It's referring to a roll of Canadian pennies. Pennies are rolled in quantities of 50 and they are saying that, at the time, a single Canadian penny was worth approximately $20 American dollars. This meant a roll of 50 was worth 1,000 American dollars.

Comment: Really appreciate your explanation,grealtly explained.Hank